# DIY minimal install debian nftables routing not working

Tags: networking, router, debian, routing, nftables

I'm trying to build a router on Debian OS and PC-hardware with several network interfaces.
Installed minimal debian-12.2.0-amd64 and trying to implement routing between init7_WAN and Carbon_LAN.
But I don't get internet connection from Windows 10 client plugged to Carbon_LAN :(

Ping on Debian router to any domain works fine.

Ping on Windows client to router works fine.

**MY PROBLEM NOW:** Ping on Windows client to any domain fails.

**MY QUESTION: How to troubleshoot my ping?**

***I'm a beginner in Linux and would be very thankful for the troubleshooting direction. I will pay you with my leg or something...***

I did not configure other LAN interface and did not install DHCP/DNS servers for the sake of simplicity following instructions [here 1](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Simple_ruleset_for_a_home_router)

Comment: One problem (which might or might not be the cause) is that you somehow configure two interfaces (which are apparently not bridged) with IPs from the same IP subnet. As for the approach to troubleshoot, you may see if `tcpdump` (e.g. capturing the icmp traffics while `ping`'ing `8.8.8.8`) can give you any hint. Also, make sure you check with `iptables-save` (and `nft list ruleset`) to confirm whether there's something else that also messes with your firewall.

Comment: Remember that routing is symmetrical, unless NAT is used. You need a route to reach the world, but the world also needs a route to reach you. I would suggest getting a book on TCP/IP, because the problem appears to be understanding routing, not configuring things

Comment: @vidarlo To be fair, NAT is being used: `-A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0f1 -j MASQUERADE`.

Comment: @TomYan Ah, thanks. Didn't notice :)

Comment: Dear all, thanks for your input! I have put LAN interfaces on different subnets, removed iptables and installed nftables and provided output from "nft list ruleset" as well as tcpdump. Would appreciate a hint where to dig further!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Debian instead of the router-centric Linux distributions where you configure them from a website like store routers? Openwrt might be a good start

Comment: Thank you Gregg for your time and question! Yes, I would like to learn and use podman technology in parallel on my router (and then run a webserver for websites and market research on it).

Answer (score 0):

I HAVE SOLVED MY ISSUE WITH THE FOLLOWING CONFIGURATIONS

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface init7_WAN
allow-hotplug enp2s0f1
iface enp2s0f1 inet dhcp

# The interface Carbon_LAN
allow-hotplug eno2
iface eno2 inet static
address 192.168.100.190
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.100.255
network 192.168.100.0

# The interface WiFi_LAN
allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.168.101.190
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.101.255
network 192.168.101.0
```

**/etc/sysctl**

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

**/etc/nftables.conf**

```
# --- /etc/nftables.conf
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f
#local = eno2
#wan = enp2s0f1
#
#
flush ruleset
 
table inet filter {
chain input {
type filter hook input priority 0;
iif eno2 accept comment "allow local packets"
iif enp2s0f1 ct state {established, related} counter accept comment "allow esablished wan packets"
iif enp2s0f1 drop
}
chain forward {
type filter hook forward priority 0;
iif enp2s0f1 oif eno2 ct state {established, related} counter accept comment "allow wan est, relat"
iif eno2 oif enp2s0f1 counter accept comment "allow lan to wan"
iif enp2s0f1 ip daddr 192.168.100.190 tcp dport {https} counter accept comment "forward https"
iif enp2s0f1 drop
}
chain output {
type filter hook output priority 0;
}
}
 
table nat {
chain output {
type nat hook output priority -100;
}
chain prerouting {
type nat hook prerouting priority -100;
iif enp2s0f1 tcp dport {https} counter dnat to 192.168.100.190 comment "forward https to 190"
}
chain postrouting {
type nat hook postrouting priority 100;
oif enp2s0f1 counter masquerade comment "masquerade"
}
}
```

**network interface on Windows 10 client**

```
IP-Address: 192.168.100.191
Subnet prefix length: 24
Gateway: 192.168.100.190
DNS1: 1.1.1.1
DNS0: 1.0.0.1
```